# VBA FileFolderExists pass variable

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I found this function on a web

```
    Private Function FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo EarlyExit
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString then
        FileFolderExists = True
    End If

    EarlyExit:
    On Error GoTo 0
    End Function
```

And I want to pass string variable like this

```
    Dim lineText As String
    ...
    ElseIf FileFolderExists(lineText) = False Then
```

I am getting compile error "byref argument type mismatch"

When I put byval before strFullPath, it doesn't seem to work properly.
I also tried playing with Dir function, it works if I pass literal like "C:\test", but it doesn't work if I pass the variable.

Does anyone have function that check for folder existence and accepts the string variable as parameter ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: on which line are you getting the error

Comment: For code above : on the last line I wrote.

When passing string variable lineText when calling Function

Comment: The code posted works fine for me in both Excel and Word.  One thing, check if you have missing references in you vba project (in the Tools/Reference menu).  Sometimes missing references can cause misleading compile errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that Word adds CR character to every paragraph, or, to be more exact, that the `Text` property of the `Paragraph` object returns the paragraph text plus the CR character.

AFAIK, this is the Word's behaviour for every paragraph, even for the last one.

How can this cause a compile error, I do not have a clue. If I take Milan's example:

```
Private Sub FirstLineFolder()
Dim lineText As String

lineText = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
lineText = Left(lineText, Len(lineText) - 1) 'see below

MsgBox DoesFolderExist("C:\") 
MsgBox DoesFolderExist(lineText)
End Sub
```

it returns `true`, `true` if the first line of the document is a valid folder. If I comment the marked line, the program still compiles and runs and returns `true`, `false` (with the same document).

There is some info about it on [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx0x9x4d.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Function FolderExists(folderPath As String) As Boolean

Dim f As Object
Set f = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

On Error GoTo NotFound
Dim ff As Object
Set ff = f.GetFolder(folderPath)
FolderExists = True
Exit Function

NotFound:
FolderExists = False
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

I used the following to test it:

```
Sub Tst()

Dim b As Boolean
Dim s As String
s = "c:\temp"
b = FolderExists(s)

End Sub
```

And it works as expected.

Generally, I used `Scripting.FileSystemObject` for all file-related operation in VBA, the native functions are too cumbersome.

It should be also noted that my function all checks for folders, while the original function -- judging by its name -- perhaps also tried to check for existence of files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work for me too. I will post the new code in separate post, it should explain better what I need

Answer (score 0):

New code, it explains exactly what I need, it should be easier for you to try.

I am expecting folder in first line of the Word document, then I have to check if it exists.

```
Private Sub FirstLineFolder()
Dim lineText As String

lineText = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).range.Text

MsgBox DoesFolderExists("C:\") ' this works
MsgBox DoesFolderExists(lineText) ' this doesnt work, when same folder passed
End Sub
```

Both my and Martin's function are throwing compiling error I wrote in my first post.

If it matters : Word is 2010, "option explicit" isn't written (I inherited the code, I can't change that)

Comment: I tried your code (with my function) in my Word 2010 and it works all right. As an aside, add line `lineText = Left(lineText, Len(lineText) - 1)` to your code, `range.Text` returns the string plus ending paragraphs character.

Comment: Yes, I found it too ! I have one ghost Chr(13) at the end. Carriage Return.

That was the problem, not passing a variable.

Thanks for your help ! Btw, is each line ended with CR in Word ? You have some link that documents it, or maybe a way to see CR LF marks in Word ?

Would you like to post it as a separate answer, so I can accept it and give you the credits ?